# HTTPS Connections with Proxy cause SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, proxy

I have been struggling with this issue for some days now and I can't seem to find a useful answer...

I have some Software that causes SSLHandshakeExceptions each time I want to use it with a Proxy server. I have been able to replicate the issue with the following code (that is way simpler than the real application):

```
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://www.google.com").openConnection();
    try {
        con.connect();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I run this code connected to a WiFi Hotspot (no proxy server needed), I get the connection and everything works just as expected:

```
java -cp . SampleJavaURLTest
```

However, If I run the same Java command with a Proxy Server:

```
java -cp . -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost={myProxyHost} -DproxyPort={myProxyPort} SampleJavaURLTest
```

I get this Exception (printed with the `e.printStackTrace()` that is in the code snipplet to make line numbers irrelevant:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1731)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1197)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1181)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
at SampleJavaURLTest.main(SampleJavaURLTest.java:116)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
... 11 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
... 17 more
```

So, first logical advice would be "Use the InstallCert program and add google´s certificate". However that's not the issue, somehow Java is not liking the way certificates are handled through the proxy server.

I am running both samples with exact the same JVM, no further configuration changes other than the proxy settings in the command line. In fact, both tests were done with the same Console Window, only seconds between both tests needed to switch networks... Here's a java -v printout:

```
java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And, to be 100% sure, I also tested with a newer JVM:

```
java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
```

As a workaround, I disabled all Certificate validation by using this approach:

http://code.google.com/p/misc-utils/wiki/JavaHttpsUrl

Although it doesn't really affect me and I can live with this workaround (not so critical if someone hacks in the communication with a false certificate), I would really like to know how to properly get the certificates to work as they should. What am I missing?

Comment: Try [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/)

Comment: Sorry, but I have done that as I explained, the ssl connection works fine without the proxy server. What am I missing?

Comment: Try it with `-Dhttps.proxyHost=...` and `https.proxyPort=...`, and also `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`, and post the part before the failure here, specifically the initial `ClientHello` and the `Certificate` message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand you right your SSL connection succeeds without proxy, also succeeds with a proxy if you disable certificate validation but fails with a proxy if you enable certificate validation. In this case the proxy is tampering with the SSL, e.g. it does a man-in-the-middle attack (also called SSL interception in some firewalls or SSL bump in squid). If this is not an attack but a known feature of this proxy (e.g. to scan SSL connections for viruses etc) you need to import the proxies interception CA, because due to the man-in-the-middle you don't talk any longer SSL to the web server but to the proxy and the proxy then talks SSL to the server.

Comment: Well, this answser sounds right to me. It is a corporate proxy so I am sure it is not an "attack", but the interception CA sounds plausible to me. Issue is that I cannot use the InstallCert as it makes a "native" ssl Socket that is not detected by the proxy settings. Is there a way to adapt the InstallCert program to be able to connect through the proxy? Or, is there another way of doing it?

Comment: I don't know about InstallCert but if you can connect through the proxy with a normal web browser there should be the needed proxy CA in the browsers/systems certificate store and you should be able to export it. I don't know enough about Javas certificate management on how you do install it then for use in Java.

Comment: OK, thank you. I just checked the certificate for https://www.google.com and it´s not issued by google, but by the company that hosts the proxy server, so this confirms that your answer is right, and now it makes a lot of sense...